# Java: Why a method called inside another method is called automatically with the current calling object in Java?

Tags: java

I have a method that return a boolean value if two object (arrays) have the same average. Inside the body of the method a 3rd party method is called ( average() ). When the 3rd party method is called , it's called automatically for the current object. Why is that?

```
boolean sameAvg(GenBoundedType<?> i){
        if(average() == i.average()) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

It's redundant to call average with "this": if(this.average() == i.average()) because the calling is automatically made for the current calling object.
If somebody of good will can explain why the average() method inside sameAvg() is called automatically for the current calling object.

Comment: Why wouldn't that be the case? Why would you expect it to *not* behave like that?

Comment: because the code is written to do that. Your instance method average() is called twice, once for the instance i, and once for the current instance

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'm new to programming, and I want to know what is the process behind. I figure myself that the calling is made automatically but I want to know if it is something more than that (like many things in Java).

Comment: Side note: you can shorten the code `return average() == i.average();`

Comment: @B001ᛦ Yes, it's more better. Thank you! It's an example from Herbert Schild's book and it's probably made for teaching purpose. But it's more better you're shorten version.

Comment: It does that in Java because this is how language rules are defined, nothing more and nothing less. There's not really a good "why" to these types of questions, but you can always look through [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html) which talks about what the language is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java all the objects have some behavior (methods).
When calling a method you basically what a specific object to exercise some particular behavior.

In case the developer omits (does not specify) the object, the Java compiler assumes the method is called on the current object, i.e. "this".

The code in the question could be significantly improved to become more clean and expressive:

```
boolean sameAvg(GenBoundedType<?> i){
        return average() == i.average();
    }
```

Upd. One should also keep in mind that the comparison of floating-point numbers is a relative thing. So the method in question may produce unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you @DmitryF ! This is the kind of answer that I have expecting for. I want to upvote the answer but I haven't yet  the privilege .

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how the language is defined.

As per the [specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1)

> If the form is `MethodName` - that is, just an Identifier - then:
>
> - [...] let `T` be the enclosing type declaration of which the method is a member, and let `n` be an integer such that `T` is the `n`'th lexically enclosing type declaration of the class whose declaration immediately contains the method invocation. The target reference is the `n`'th lexically enclosing instance of `this`.

Which is a long (and formal) way to say that, in your case, `this` is implicitly added before that method call.

Comment: thank you a lot. I was  hoping to see something from the specs.